# Window.atob in HTML DOM

Tags: html, jquery, dom, xhtml

I have recevied a spam in my inbox with a filename `Open 74218.xhtml`. I opened this file with notepad++ and this is what inside the file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><body onload="document.location.replace(window.atob('aHR0cDovL3N2ZWdhazAxLnByby96cmcyU3Y/WlFJRFFDQUog'));" />
```

What does this line mean? Is it dangerous if I tried to open such files directly?

Comment: You can execute the "`window.atob(...)`" in your console safely. This will be an harmless string, which is also an URL that this script was trying to make you go to. In your position I would avoid going there, not sure what awaits there, probably just a trigger to say "this email address is valid and used by its owner, let's send them more spam or sell it to someone who will", could be more nefarious. However I'm not sure how this question fits with SO's model...

Comment: Thanks a lot for this information. I can see replace function. What is replaced in the url string?

Comment: It's not the string that is replaced, but the current location, to that URL